# numpy poly() and roots() aren't reversible?

Tags: python, numpy

I expected the poly() and roots() functions to be each other's inverse.  However, this isn't quite true:

```
# Polys coeffs
pol_c = np.poly([-1, 1, 1, 10]) # Get Polynomial coeffs for eqt with stated roots
# Roots from the poly equation
root_val = np.roots(pol_c)
# Roots from the poly equation, manually entered as integers
roots_v2 = np.roots([1,-11,9,11,-10])

print(pol_c)
print(root_val)
print(roots_v2)
```

Gives

> [1. -11.   9.  11. -10.]
>
> [10.+0.0000000e+00j -1.+0.0000000e+00j  1.+9.6357437e-09j
>     1.-9.6357437e-09j]
>
> [10.+0.0000000e+00j -1.+0.0000000e+00j  1.+9.6357437e-09j
>     1.-9.6357437e-09j]

ie. the 3rd & 4th roots are (slightly) imaginary instead of real

My first thought was floating point error, but given that roots() outputs the same answer for *float* and *int* inputs that seems not to be the case.  Plus I would expect poly() to give non-integer answers if floating point accuracy was limiting the solves.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at with the "1 vs 10" issue, those all look right to me.  All the root finding happens in the complex space, so it's not surprising we get complex results out, or that there's a slight error in the output.

Comment: You're right.  Got distracted as I was submitting and thought "oh, I missed an order of magnitude error, weird".  Then quickly added it to the question.  edited to fix

Comment: What is your question? Why it's not the same result? Why there is a complex component? Whether the two are their respective inverses at all?

Comment: Yes my question is those things. Obviously poly and roots are theoretical inverses but they are failing to be so. Why?

Answer (score 2):

The functions are inverses of each other, within some computational errors (which may be complex), and up to reordering of roots.

```
pol_c = np.poly([-1, 1, 1, 10]) 
root_val = np.roots(pol_c)
print(np.real_if_close(np.around(root_val, 6)))
```

prints `[10. -1.  1.  1.]` which is the same as we started with, in another order.

Of course, the order need not be the same: the original order of roots is lost when `pol_c` was formed, and  there is no canonical order for the roots of polynomials (which are generally complex) anyway.

Comment: Thanks! So it's a limitation of the underlying solver in roots()?  I'd expected convergence better than 10e-9 in a toy example with an exact solution.

Comment: You've got a double root there. Note that the coefficients of `(x - 1.+9.6357437e-09j)(x - 1.-9.6357437e-09j)` are indistinguishable from those of `(x - 1)^2` at double precision, so from a numerical perspective those roots are just as plausible. There's no way the solver can tell that `1` and `1` are the "correct" roots: that information just isn't there any more in the polynomial coefficients.

Comment: hm? Sorry, I don't get it -- Doubles contain 16 sig figs of information.  Why is the solver  limited to e-9 accuracy?   I can understand if the solver terminated at precision less than the floating point accuracy, but it's possible to refine further if necessary right?

Comment: @Mark_Anderson The number x=1e-9 satisfies the equation `1-x**2 = 1` in double precision. There is nothing to refine, the equation is perfectly solved as far as the solver can tell. The take-away is that multiple roots are more tricky than simple once